# Trying to post data via wp ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make a jquery ajax call but I am unable to do do this can anyone help me out of this?

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contact-me" id="contact-me">
<div class="form-field">    
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Type your name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-field">    
    <label>Email: </label>
    <input name="email"  type="email" placeholder="Type a valid email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-field">    
    <label>Name: </label>
    <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Type your comment" required></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_form" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
<button id="backup_button" type="button">Send message!</button>
```

My jquery code

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
$('#backup_button').on('click', function(e) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

});

Here Is my PHP code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
    die('ddd');
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your response? Do you get contact with your action?

Try to remove your "die('ddd');" and before your wp_die() you should either echo or return something.

Comment: The response I am getting is 0

Comment: why u added die('ddd'); in your action

Comment: I want to display some results in a response. But if I add or not result will be same